# Display HTML field

Tags: views, theming

I am using [Views Database Connector](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_database_connector) to display safe data from external database in Drupal 8 within views. Some of the fields include simple html like a list which views encodes in html entities. I am using `{{ fields.myfield.content }}` in views-view-fields--myview.html.twig.
I have searched for other solutions about using the raw value on the site but none of them seems to work.

Is there a simple solution without getting involved in preprocess functions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if a module exists for this yet, but to do this, you would need to create a field handler for Views that does not escape HTML.

Here is an example I made a year ago to achieve the same thing you are trying to do.

For the field handler, I implemented this hook to change what handled the data:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 *
 * We need to look through and change the field handler for our stored item to
 * our custom handler so HTML is unescaped.
 *
 * @param array $data
 */
function search_api_view_modes_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $indices = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('search_api_index')->loadMultiple();
  $views_data_keys = array_keys($data);

  if ($indices) {
    foreach (array_keys($indices) as $index) {
      $views_index_name = 'search_api_index_' . $index;

      if (!in_array($views_index_name, $views_data_keys)) {
        continue;
      }

      foreach (array_keys($data[$views_index_name]) as $item) {
        if (preg_match('/^view_mode_(.*)/', $item)) {
          $data[$views_index_name][$item]['field']['id'] = 'search_api_view_mode';
          $data[$views_index_name][$item]['field']['fallback_handler'] = 'search_api_view_modes';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anytime one of my fields was seen in a View, the field handler was set to `search_api_view_mode`, defined below:

```
/**
 * Provides a default handler for rendered entity view modes in Search API Views.
 *
 * @ingroup views_field_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsField("search_api_view_mode")
 */
class SearchApiViewMode extends FieldPluginBase implements MultiItemsFieldHandlerInterface {

  use SearchApiFieldTrait;

  /**
   * Overrides render_item to return our markup unescaped.
   * @param $count
   * @param $item
   * @return string
   */
  public function render_item($count, $item) {
    return check_markup($item['value'], 'full_html');
  }

}
```

`check_markup` is probably not advised anymore, over a Markup object, but nonetheless this is what I had to do to not have the HTML escaped. I am not sure you can reverse this at the twig level.

Comment: Thank you for your solution Kevin, but is there no way of using the equivalent of html_entity_decode or raw within twig?
I did come across the [link](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value)twig Field Value module.

Comment: I believe the problem is with Views, and not general field level rendering.

Comment: Problem as in, where you need to handle it. Not a bug.

Comment: Hi Kevin , sorry to ask, but I am more of a Drupal site builder than a developer, so where would I use this code, in the theme overide or create a custom module? Thanks

Comment: You would have to make a custom module. hook_views_data_alter can only be called at the module layer, and your module would contain a plugin at src/Plugin/views/field/(class name).php.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a best practice, but I was able to get a field from an external database that contained HTML to print using the markup, instead of printing out the tags by doing the following in twig (in Drupal 8.5.3).  I used the raw field contents and wrapped that in autoescape false.

In my case I put it in a views-view-fields-MY_VIEW_NAME.html.twig template in my theme using the following:

```
{% autoescape false %}{{ field.raw }}{% endautoescape %}
```

I'm imagining that you could use something like [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) and Rewrite Results of MY_FIELD directly in Views to do this, also:

```
{% autoescape false %}{{ MY_FIELD|raw }}{% endautoescape %}
```

I know it's a bit late, but hopefully it'll help other Googlers like me.